# Small bluetooth chip to connect a phone with

Tags: integrated-circuit, bluetooth

i'm looking for a small bluetooth chip which i can connect my phone with.

The idea is that i should be able to send a command to that chip with my phone. In return that chip should do something. For example, play a beep tone (i think that is a simple thing?).

I'd like to power the chip with a small flat battery that you find in watches (f possible). Also the smaller the chip the better. I don't mind to solder parts together if needed.

I just have no idea what kind of chips are out there since my expertise is just normal software programming. I'd just like to extend my knowledge a bit with fun side projects like this :)

So anyone any idea how i can get started with this? What chip do i need and what cicuitboards? Or whatever is needed.

Comment: Please consider reading up a bit on electronic design as a basis for attacking this project... First, blink an LED. Then blink that LED using a microcontroller. Then, blink the LED via a Bluetooth command. After that, look at powering the Bluetooth module with a CR2032 battery. *Then* start examining the beep tone output options.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Ok, i thought that what i wanted was a simple thing. Guess i have to take a few steps back :) Do you have any recommendations with what kind of `LED`s and `microcontrollers` i can best start with?

Comment: If you would have done more research on Bluetooth and BLE, you would have found the answers quickly. There were other posts on this topic before and looking at them would have been better.

Comment: This is actually a good question: what's unfortunate is that so many have missed the glaring issue in all such projects, which is compatibility of various embedded bluetooth modules with different phones.  Basically, iphones won't talk to modules hobbyists can buy, unless they are the newer bluetooth EDR, however older android and perhaps iphone devices won't talk to those.  Unless it duplicates an existing question with good answers, there's a lot of important information to be covered here, before the poster wastes a lot of time and money on paths that will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the C2540 mini devkit from TI, they have examples on how to hook it up to an iphone.  I have one of these kits and it works pretty well.  Notice it's already powered by a coin cell.   Here's the link to the [kit](http://www.ti.com/tool/CC2540DK-MINI).   You can find several examples of how to code it up online.

[image]